# Where is Baobab config file?

Tags: disk-usage

Does Baobab have a config file, or is it configured in a file somewhere.  I am running Kubuntu 16.04 xenial.

Comment: What do you want to configure?

Comment: On 14.04, it stores some settings in dconf at org.gnome.baobab - might be different on 16.04.

Comment: Tx wjandrea, just learning about how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04 Baobab configuration is available inside 'org/gnome/baobab/preferences' from `dconf-editor` (as **wjandrea** suggested).

Available options are listed in */usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.baobab.gschema.xml* :

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -i baobab | sort | uniq 
org.gnome.baobab.preferences excluded-uris @as []
org.gnome.baobab.ui active-chart 'rings'
org.gnome.baobab.ui window-size (960, 600)
org.gnome.baobab.ui window-state 128
```

Comment: Tx, just what I needed.